# How to change Coverage class for SimpleCov

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simplecov

I am getting `Coverage is not a class (TypeError)`

I have already a coverage class in my model and I added gem 'SimpleCov' and when I run Spec then Getting `Coverage is not a class (TypeError)`.

The error comes because of coverage class in my model. so Is there any way to change coverage class in SimpleCov and give another name for that class?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Just created an empty class named `Coverage` in my rails application. Everything works fine. I have `simplecov 0.9.0`. What version do you use?

Comment: are you using jruby? https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov/blob/5143ee61a995a8c5e385b931631938590995615f/lib/simplecov/jruby_fix.rb

Comment: hi @phoet yes, I am using simplecov but not jruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author of simplecov [stated](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov/issues/48) that the Coverage class is in Ruby and so this is not something he can fix. I would suggest refactoring your schema to rename your Coverage class.

Answer (score 0):

Could you namespace your Coverage class? In that way will not be collision. You will need refactor your code.